# SDL2 pcm audio playing too fast

Tags: c++, sdl, pcm, sdl-mixer

I wrote a library to read unsigned 8 bit pcm audio from a old game and I stuffed the raw data into a Mix_Chunk using this code:

```
Mix_Chunk sfx;
sfx.allocated = 1;
sfx.abuf = (Uint8*)data;
sfx.alen = length;
sfx.volume = 32;
```

I know the samplerate is 10989HZ but when I set the sample rate using `Mix_OpenAudio(10989, AUDIO_U8, 2, 2048`
it plays the sound way too fast, am I setting the sample rate wrong or is it just SDL2 not liking PCM?

if I dump it into a file and open it with Audacity it plays just fine

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @akk0rd87 sorry fixed the post

Comment: Wild guess: you have mono data, but declare two channels. This would typically cause the data to be interpreted as interleaved channels, and thus played twice as fast.

Comment: @Quentin declaring only one channel doesn't fix the problem

Comment: If you call [Mix_QuerySpec](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_15.html#SEC15) does it say the correct frequently?

Comment: @user253751 yes

Answer (score 1):

fixed the problem, before you call Mix_OpenAudio run this:

```
SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
SDL_memset(&wavSpec, 0, sizeof(wavSpec)); /* or SDL_zero(want) */

wavSpec.callback = audioCallback;
wavSpec.userdata = nullptr;
wavSpec.format = AUDIO_S16;
wavSpec.channels = 2;
wavSpec.samples = 2048;

if (SDL_OpenAudio(&wavSpec, NULL) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

pcm audio plays correctly now